# Why The 2D Matrix does not print the same input values?

Tags: c, matrix

Below is the program I tried.

I get the 2D array and print that array just after the all elements are scanned
like below

```
int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    int R, C;
    scanf("%d %d", &R, &C);
    int i[C][R];

    for (int row = 0; row < R; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < C; column++) {
            int val = 0;
            scanf("%d", &val);
            i[row][column] = val;
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < R; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < C; column++) {
            printf("%d \t", i[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("RotatedMatrix\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I give the input as `3,4` indicating 3 rows and 4 columns so totally 12 elements

I give the input from 1 to 12 for matrix

But the output matrix looks like below

```
1   2   3   5   
5   6   7   9   
9   10  11  12
```

Instead of

```
1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   
9   10  11  12
```

The elements on last column is changed like above

I can't figure out what I am missing. It would be helpful if I get any help

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d",&R,&C);
    int i[C][R];` --> `scanf("%d %d", &R,&C);
    int i[R][C];`

Comment: Look at the declaration, and how you use `C` and `R`. Then look at where you use the array, and how you use the rows and columns. Compare the declaration with the usage.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, post code that cleanly compiles, including the #include statements,  Otherwise we are only guessing about what header files the actual code actually includes

Comment: when asking the user for some specific input, always prompt the user, so they know what is expected.  Otherwise this code outputs "!!!Hello Worldl!!!" then leaves the user staring at a that text and a blinking cursor and no indication of what they are expected to do next,

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this statement in your question: "input as 3,4"  the call to `scanf()` has no provision for the comma `,` so will not input the two values.  Suggest not separating the values by anything but white space.

Comment: when coding, use meaningful names.  the declared variables `R` and `C` and not really meaningful.  Suggest using: `numRows` and `numColumns`.  Similar considerations pertain to the array `i[][]`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for pointing out those issues in the code other than bugs next time i will make sure not to to them again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
int i[R][C];
```

instead of

```
int i[C][R];
```